# window.open not working in IE 9, 64 Bit OS

Tags: javascript, operating-system

I am working in javascript. I had opened a window using window.open. Its working fine in IE 9, 32 bit OS but its not working in 64 Bit OS. What is the relationship between window.open and 64 bit OS.

How to fix this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem people are having with 32-bit Internet Explorer on 64-bit Windows operating systems. It has to do with the popup blocker, and even when disabled in Internet Explorer it will not completely disable it for the 32-bit IE, so a registry hack is sometimes required.

I had a similar issue and resolved said issue by not using window.open anymore! There is no issue with your code - it is an issue with Internet Explorer (but what else is new?).

Comment: i want to open my page in Full Screen. so that i had used window.open.. without using window.open what will be the solution here....